# Plotting a 2D histogram with 2 data sets

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have been trying to plot a 2D histogram from two sets of data. I have tried two different ways and haven't had any success. The two data sets are an array, 101 bins long. Each bin contains a count for an event happening. For both of the graphs it ends up outputting it looks very linear when the graph should look more like a peak in the center and a taper outwards. Below are sample of what the data looks like.

The two ways I have tried graph them looks as such,

```
xdata = [0,0,1,2,3,5,3,2,1,0,0]
ydata = [0,0,1,2,3,5,3,2,1,0,0]
plt.hist2d(xdata, ydata, bins=(101, 101), cmap=plt.cm.winter)
plt.show()
```

and

```
xbins = 101
ybins = 101
xdata = [0,0,1,2,3,5,3,2,1,0,0]
ydata = [0,0,1,2,3,5,3,2,1,0,0]
H, xbins, ybins = np.histogram2d(xdata, ydata, bins=(xbins, ybins))
H = H.T
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(9, 9))
ax = fig.add_subplot(132, title='pcolormesh: actual edges',
    aspect='equal')
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xbins, ybins)
ax.pcolormesh(X, Y, H)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I think the issue is that you're passing the counts of binned data when `plt.hist2d` expects the raw data to be passed to the parameters `x` and `y`. A heatmap generated from your counts should accomplish the same thing as a 2d histogram, as long as we know the range of your x and y data.